# How to get the theme that the current user use in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I develop the intellij plugin, but some backgroud color in Windows Theme and Darcula Theme show very different.

How to get the intellij theme in plugin code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIUtil.isUnderDarcula()` does what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can also make use of `JBColor` which displays differently under different themes.